# Copy an array into the end of a larger array

Tags: java

I want to copy an array into a larger array, but instead of starting at the first element or a specified element, such as System.arraycopy(), I want it to start at the last element and move backward.

```
int [] ary1 = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
int [] ary2 = new int [10];
```

and I want the elements in ary2 to equal

```
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5
```

or

```
null,null,null,null,null,1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Ok but any attempt from your side ?

Comment: could you please post what you have tried ???

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int- can't you use dstPos??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `System.arrayCopy()` for that purpose. Since you use an array of primitive `int` type, the resulting array will be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

```
System.arraycopy(ary1, 0, ary2, 5, ary1.length);
```

The arguments are:

1. Source-array
2. Start-position in source-array
3. Destination-array
4. Start-position in destination-array
5. Number of elements to copy

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work 
int [] ary1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int [] ary2 = new int [10];
    int y = ary2.length-1;
    for (int i = ary1.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
        ary2[y]=ary1[i];
        y--;
    }
```